# Execute in Swagger UI Taking Time to Display the Result

Tags: java, jersey, swagger, swagger-ui, jersey-2.0

There are two APIs built using swagger (1.5), Jersey Framework (2.25) etc. 1) To load a file 2) To Track the status of the file

When file is in the middle of load, track status (after clicking on execute) shows the same (file is in progress) but when file is loaded successfully, database shows "file is loaded successfully" and query to track the status also shows the same but in UI (after clicking on execute), it still shows the "file is in progress".

If cache is cleared & tried again then in UI (after clicking on execute) shows the expected status (file is loaded successfully) in Track Status API.

What could be the possible root cause for this?

Can you please help?

Answer (score 2):

Get requests are cacheable by default. Browsers treat all GET requests cacheable. POST requests are not cacheable by default but can be cacheable after doing some code changes. PUT and DELETE requests are not cacheable at all.

Reference Links:

1. https://www.imperva.com/learn/performance/cache-control/#:~:text=Cache%2DControl%3A%20No%2DCache,request%20to%20an%20origin%20server.
2. https://restfulapi.net/caching/